# Install Windows 7 and Mac OS on a laptop

Tags: windows-7, macos, multi-boot

I have an Intel Core 2 Duo laptop. I already have Windows 7 in one partition but now I want to install Mac OS in the other partition. Is it possible and how can I boot into both partitions at will? I would prefer it to work just like Mac bootcamp.

Comment: Mac OS? What for? Why not at least put on OS X?

Comment: We don't answer "Hackintosh" questions.

Answer (score 1):

Well installing MacOS as native OS on a regular Laptop is not that easy, I've already tried to do so on 2 PC's and 1 laptop. It never worked. What works great for me is running it inside a Virtual Machine. Depending on what you want to do and how fast your system is it can be a bit slow. But it works for me and I develop private little iPhone Apps/Gadgets.